# left join not giving correct output

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I am having 2 table

**tableA**

```
Accountid   
-----------  
10  
11  
12
```

**tableB**

```
Accountid   |   Date        |   
--------------------------------------------    
10      |   2016-02-02  |   
11      |   2016-02-02  |   
11      |   2016-02-02  |    
15      |   2016-02-03  |
```

I am expecting the output like

```
Accountid   |   ID  |   
------------------------------------    
10      |   10  |   
11      |   11  |   
12      |   NULL    |
```

I am running this query

```
select A.accountid,b.accountid as ID 
from tableA as A 
left join tableB as B on a.accountid=b.accountid 
where b.date between '2016-02-02' and '2016-02-02'
```

but it is giving me the output as, I am not sure where am I going wrong

```
Accountid   |   ID  |   
----------------------------------- 
10      |   10  |   
11      |   11  |
```

I am using MSSQL database.

Comment: Move `b.date between '2016-02-02' and '2016-02-02'` into the join condition. Putting it into the `where` turns the outer join into an inner join

Comment: it is due to where b.date between '2016-02-02' and '2016-02-02'..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is not true that its where condition turns the meaning of join from left to inner. it would be true only if he puts  a.accountid=b.accountid in where clause

Comment: @MtwStark: if the condition on the outer table uses values that should not be null then the `where` condition **will** make the query behave like an inner join.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we do not know if date field is NOT NULL, the join condition is executed first, it can retreive any row with or without nullable fields.. what you filter after with the WHERE clause could be different from result of INNER JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When any field of the right table of a left join is occurred in `WHERE` clause then this join will behave like `INNER JOIN`

To get expected result your query should be like this

```
select A.accountid,b.accountid as ID 
from tableA as A 
left join tableB as B on a.accountid=b.accountid and 
                         b.date between '2016-02-02' and '2016-02-02'
```

Comment: Actually, you mean 'any field of the **right** table of a **left** join' .

Comment: @JaydipJ what if I have 2 accountid as 11 for the same date and i want to show 11 only once. I am using distinct but it is not working

Comment: if you have same account id and same date the Distinct` must be work, You missing something while using Distinct

Comment: @JaydipJ moving the date condition to ON clause is correct, but it is not true that its where condition turns the meaning of join from left to inner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select A.accountid,b.accountid as ID 
from tableA as A left join tableB as B on a.accountid=b.accountid 
where b.date is null or b.date between '2016-02-02' and '2016-02-02'
```

The reason is, for AccountID 12 b.date is effectively null (because there's no row in tableB). Therefore you'll only get a result for that row if you allow date to be null in the query.

Comment: Be carreful , if b.date can really get null value you will have not expected results, the real solution to add filter in the "ON" clause

Answer (score 0):

If b does not exist (id = 12) your where clause return false .
 if you want to see the row with id=12 you must include your test (b.date between '2016-02-02' and '2016-02-02') with your "ON" clause :

```
   select A.accountid,b.accountid as ID from tableA as A left join tableB as B 
on a.accountid=b.accountid and b.date between '2016-02-02' and '2016-02-02'
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason is because the WHERE clause of your select is executed after the LEFT JOIN

so, first sql server will extract the data as you expect, with the row 12-NULL,

and then it will be filtered out and removed from output by your WHERE clause

you can move the date filter on JOIN condition as suggested by @JaydipJ and @RémyBaron

or filter the tableB before the JOIN this way:

```
select A.accountid,b.accountid as ID 
from tableA as A 
left join (
  select * 
  from tableB 
  where b.date between '2016-02-02' and '2016-02-02'
) as B on a.accountid=b.accountid
```